# Why am I losing bonds when I use PACKMOL on two proteins?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software, docking, covid-19, packmol

I recently started using [PACKMOL](http://m3g.iqm.unicamp.br/packmol/home.shtml) to pack a few proteins together. I wrote this PACKMOL code:

```
tolerance 3.0
filetype pdb
output E_S.pdb

structure E.pdb
  number 1
  inside box -44. 0. 0. 156. 50. 130.
  center
  fixed 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
end structure

structure 6vxx.pdb
  number 1
  inside box -44. 50. 0. 100. 200. 150.
  center
  fixed 0. 116. 0. 4.71238898 0. 0.
end structure
```

This code is to fix/attach one protein (SARS-CoV-2 Spike glycoprotein) onto another (SARS-CoV-2 Membrane protein)
I ended up fixing different values so that the structure would look like its attached.
When the code ran and the structure was generated the "Bonds" checkbox when visualized in the software [OVITO](https://www.ovito.org/docs/current/) was found missing meaning **there is no bonding that exists**.

Why did this happen?

Comment: packmol is not designed to fix proteins together as far as I know.

Comment: It is used to build and pack atoms and molecules. But even if it isn't proteins, the bonding is lost!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because packmol isn't designed for this purpose.

Comment: I don't see any need to close the question.

Comment: @CodyAldaz I would be grateful if you could retract your close vote now. The asker was concerned because bonds disappeared when he put 2 proteins in in PACKMOL. There is an answer saying that the user should not use PACKMOL, therefore MMSE has helped the user solve their problem. I do not want to discourage users from asking questions here, by close or downvoting them. Eventually we shall agree on our community-specific close/downvoting policies, but for now I'd be happy if downvotes aren't used & close votes are reserved for non-matter-modeling Qs, or Qs lacking detail ***and*** abandoned.

Comment: The bonds are visualized in accordance with the set-up of each visualization software. Did you try other software like [Chimera](http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera), for example?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a protein-protein docking package instead PACKMOL, as they do not only "put" the proteins together but also dock in the must favorable conformation. (a free web server you can use is [HADDOCK](https://haddock.science.uu.nl/))

Comment: I had always used PACMOL to stack metal and lipid layers for my projects. I thought protein stacking can also be done in the same way!

Answer (score 5):

Packmol is used to pack molecules into a given box at random positions and with random rotations.

If you want the spike glycoprotein to be attached to the membrane, you should probably prepare a new structure containing the two molecules as a single unit which Packmol won't break.

Now you have achieved your goal. Next, you can use packmol for what it's really used for i.e. adding further molecules for solvation.

Comment: I haven't flagged this, but I do worry that some other people might try to flag it for conversion to a comment, especially since it fits in the comment box with even 271 more characters available.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sounds like a bug in StackExchange.

Comment: Seems to fit: "Packmol is used to pack molecules into a given box at random positions and with random rotations.

If you want the spike glycoprotein to be attached to the membrane, you should probably prepare a new structure containing the two molecules as a single unit.

Then, you can use packmol for what it's really used for i.e. adding further molecules for solvation."

Comment: @Nike this is the correct answer tho. If the answer isn't good enough then we should vote to close the question

Comment: It doesn't answer this "What can I do to restore the bonding and is there good opensource software which can help with protein attaching or as most people say docking?" The question can probably be significantly improved (I can try later when I'm back home), but closure doesn't seem right.

Comment: +1. I can try to improve it when i get home. The question about software for docking ought to maybe be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @NikeDattani the only part it doesn't answer is the bit about other software packages.

Comment: The question's title asked what happens when you put things in PACKMOL & asked about the breaking of bonds, then the question's body asked about other software packages. So at first, the answer looked to me like it skipped all that, even if it correctly said that PACKMOL isn't designed for this purpose (Cody also wrote that as a comment, and this answer was also well within the allowed comment length), so I was worried that some people might try to flag it for comment conversion if the answer didn't elaborate. Now I've improved the Q & given you +1. OP should ask a separte Q for other software

Comment: Any idea on how to prepare a new structure containing the two molecules as a single unit which Packmol won't break?

Comment: Or is is supposed to be a new question by itself?

Comment: @SaiSmaranSBPES1201701189PES This must be a separate question. You cannot expect someone that has already spent time answering one of your questions, to start answering your additional questions in comments. Every separate question should have its own separate page.